# 5 V radio on 12 V battery

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, radio, amperage, 12v

I am working on a powerbox project (12 V): charging a cell phone, lights, banana plugs and a small radio. 12 V is somewhat straightforward for me.

The radio (https://rb.gy/e6ngmo) works with 3 V to 5 V. I have found on AliExpress a "buck converter" that will give me 5 V, 3 A.

**My (neophyte) question: should I worry about amps?** Is 3 A too much for such radio?

In the radio instructions, it says: "Supply Current: maximum volume 1000 mA, minimum volume at 60 mA (for reference only)".

Thanks!

Comment: "3A" Aliexpress buck converters perform well at (and below) 1A but tend to overheat at 3A

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that Current is pulled, Voltage is pushed.

Your device will pull the current it needs. Your supply should be able to provide that much current or more. Rule of thumb is that your load should be between 10% and 80% of the supply capacity as a safety buffer and longer life (The 10% is for minimum regulation and noise minimization but thats also subjective). But these supplies also have their own tolerances and ranges. So using a 1 Amp device on a 3 Amp supply is fine.

Voltage on the other hand is pushed through regardless of what the device needs. So putting a 5V device on a 12V supply means  an unhappy end user.